# Table rowspan transparent image

Tags: image, html-table, png, transparent

I have a problem with my table. I want an image with a transparent background in the top right corner of a newsletter. Here's the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="header.png" alt="header" class="headerImg" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="circle.png" alt="header" class="rightHeaderImg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>   
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem seems to be with the rowspan, but I just think it's weird that I have a .png image with transparent background, and when it's shown in the td its background color is solid.

Comment: Can you provide us with the CSS and accompanying code? And maybe a JSFiddle? We don't know what the code is for the `class`es you provided...

Comment: which solid color you have in that table row?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site? If the problem is with a particular image, we'd like a look at it before we can provide a solution. Also, your tabel does not have a top right corner.

Comment: Since you mention newsletter, are you watching this in a browser or did you send it as an e-mail? Also if you are testing in an older browser the PNG might not work (ie 6).

Comment: There's not any style on the classes yet.. The problem also occure when just in an ordinary td. Actually it's just a table, where the img circle.png gets a solid background. The img works fine when not inside the table

Comment: @HugoDelsing I'm testing in chrome and ie8, ie9

Comment: @MrLister lister, I don't have a site up and running, sry :)

Comment: @unebune Then show the full HTML here. Does the problem only occur with that particular image, or with other transparent images too?

Comment: Can You Give us a screenshot? By pressing PRT SC button on keyboard? Add that in your question area, so it can be helpful for others!

Comment: @AspiringAqib unfortunately no, it's for a client, and I can't threw around my work with their names on it :)

Comment: oh yeah he is new comer :D Do you know how much repo is required to do that?

Comment: @unebune In that case, I don't know if we can help. Using the info you provided now, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MrLister 2sec I'm just lazy as hell this fine morning. Removing all the images from the table, but here u go http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/newslettery.png/ - the image to the left is outside the table.

Comment: @AspiringAqib Here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/newslettery.png/ - the image to the left is outside the table.

Comment: OK, and you're sure that's not just the background color of the table itself?

Comment: @MrLister No it is not. Problem is that the td that has 3 rowspan has a solid color. I can see that because the 2 other rows has 2 differnet colors, and it should be possible to see the 2 rows backgroundcolors through a transparent td which has rowspan 3 across the 2 rows with colors... The issue seems to be that I can't have a transparent .png image in a td which has rowspan 2+ ? :S

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to overlap the row below it, you can do that by having the image overflow out of the `td`, not by giving the `td` a rowspan.

So the solution becomes something like this

```
<table style="background:purple; border-spacing:0; height:112px">
  <tr>
    <td>top</td>
    <td>top</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
      <div style="height:0;"><img src="circle.png" alt=""></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#999">
    <td>bottom</td>
    <td>bottom</td>
    <td><!--empty--></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and look like this

[image]

Note that you need an extra `div` inside the td with the image, otherwise the td would expand vertically to be as high as the image (even if you were to set its height to 0 explicitly; that wouldn't help). Also note that you'll need to give the table an explicit height, otherwise it won't know how hight it needs to be to accommodate the overflowed image.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nAsR/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I want it to do:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr style="background:purple;">
    <td>top</td>
    <td>top</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="circle.png" alt="header"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#999">
    <td>bottom</td>
    <!-- room for td above -->
    <td>bottom</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the circle image in some sort of way to have its td be transparent, so that the color of both the purple tr and gray tr shows behind the image. It shouldn't be solved using divs og positioned elements.

[image]